Equivalence of morphisms under substitution
Let me introduce my original example and then we can generalize.
In a category with products, we have the diagonal morphism (WP, nLab) dup and the pairing operator pair(-, -) satisfying the point-free equivalence:
$$
pair(id,id) \cong dup : X \to X \times X
$$
Given any particular morphism $f : X \to Y$, we can also consider:
$$
pair(f,f) \cong dup \circ f : X \to Y \times Y
$$
But now let's add free monoids (WP, nLab) ("lists") and consider the nil and cons morphisms:
$$
nil : 1 \to [X]
$$
$$
cons : X \times [X] \to [X]
$$
This seems fine, but they can be arranged like so:
$$
cons \circ pair(nil, nil) : 1 \to [[X]]
$$
The inner pair can't be replaced with dup because the types don't line up; the two nil can't be unified. Indeed, cons ∘ dup is never well-typed, because cons takes inputs of different types but dup returns outputs of identical types. What went wrong here?
More generally, suppose we have an equivalence of polymorphic families of morphisms: For some objects $X, Y, \dots$, we have a diagram over those objects. Each commuting pair of morphisms in that diagram should be equivalent, even if we paste it into a larger diagram. But not all equivalences type-check under substitution. Why not?

Could be moved to CS, TCS, or PLDI. Please note: I think I understand the underlying polymorphism issues well enough to not be blocked or in need of help. Rather, I want to know exactly why multiple important principles of category theory (polymorphism, universality, diagrams, equivalences) seem to clash here and whether there's something deeper and non-obvious.

What are the types of $nil$ and $cons$ that you're using? The usage suggests that $cons$ is $[[X]] \times [[X]] \to [[X]]$, rather than the $[[X]] \times X \to [[X]]$ that I'd expect.

@AlexKruckman: Operationally, yes; in models, there might only be one empty list. However, the two nil have different inferred types; one is an empty list of X, and one is an empty list of lists of X. If we try unifying the types, we'll get a unification error.

@S.C.: Fair question! I'm giving $cons : X \times [X] \to [X]$, although you could also $flip(cons) : [X] \times X \to [X]$. Note that [X] is a list of X and [[X]] is a list of lists of X.

Oh, now that you've added more details, I understand what you're asking. Isn't the obvious issue just that the equality $pair(f,f) = dup\circ f$ only makes sense when $f$ names a single arrow, but when you write $pair(nil,nil)$, the two things called "nil" are actually two different arrows that you've given the same name? You write "Rather, I want to know exactly why multiple important principles of category theory (polymorphism, universality, diagrams, equivalences) seem to clash here" - but isn't polymorphism really an important principle of computer science, not category theory?

@AlexKruckman: Two things. First, polymorphism shows up throughout category theory; for example, the family of identity arrows is indexed by objects. Similarly, the family of empty lists is also indexed by objects (arrows $1 \to [X]$ for any object $X$). Second, as your first comment illustrates, it is not obvious that there is a type error here. It feels to category theorists as though substitution and equivalence should always play nicely together. So, when it doesn't, it's jarring. Is there a deeper explanation or is it merely asking too much from naive polymorphism?

@Corbin But category theorists don't use the same notation for all identity arrows - a subscript indicating the object is almost always used. Similarly, $X \mapsto [X]$ is a functor, and $nil$ is a natural transformation $1\to [-]$ (where $1$ is the constant functor to the terminal object), which has components $nil_X\colon 1\to [X]$ for all objects $X$. If you include the proper subscripts, you get $cons_{[X]}\circ pair_{[X],[[X]]}(nil_X,nil_{[X]})$, and the mystery vanishes.

Agreed; I used subscripts to work it out as well.

What is happening is that the example is substituting notation, but using notation that does not correspond uniquely to the actual objects that are subject to substitution. So, an equation is proved for one meaning of the notation, then used with other meanings.
The rule is:
$$\newcommand{\pair}{\mathsf{pair}} \newcommand{\dup}{\mathsf{dup}} \newcommand{\nil}{\mathsf{nil}} \newcommand{\cons}{\mathsf{cons}}
∀(f : X → Y). \pair(f,f) = \dup \circ f$$
Type theoretically, to use this with $\nil : Π_X. 1 → [X]$, you must instantiate it before you can use the rule. So every occurrence of $f$ is instantiated the same way, but in the $\cons$ example that is not the case. Just because instantiation is implicit doesn't mean it is unnecessary to keep track of it. Arguably it is difficult to do so by hand. That's where computers can help.
One could also try to prove rules for polymorphic functions. In that case, I think there are multiple possibilities, and none of them are principal (all possibilities are instantiations of a principal one) without adding more features. But we could do (adding a type ascription to make things more clear):
$$∀(f : Π_X. Y → X). \pair(f,f) = \dup \circ f : Π_X. Y → X×X$$
Here the rule is still instantiating $f$ to the same $X$ every time, because it (presumably) must to get everything to work out. You can still only apply this in situations where $f$ is instantiated the same way in both $\pair$ occurrences, which is not the case for the $\cons$ example.
We could also potentially apply the first rule with $\nil : 1 → Π_X. [X]$ to get:
$$\pair(\nil,\nil) = \dup \circ \nil : 1 → (Π_X. [X]) × (Π_X. [X])$$
And maybe this version could work if the system were to recognize that $$\cons : (Π_X. [X])×(Π_X. [[X]]) → Π_X.[[X]]$$ were a valid subtyping of $\cons$. In fact, the above polymorphic rule could be made to work with enough effort, because:
$$Π_X. 1 → [X] × [[X]] \cong \\
1 → Π_X. [X] × [[X]] \cong \\
1 → (Π_X. [X]) × (Π_X. [[X]])$$
However, handling situations like this automatically can get very complicated/impossible, and it's not always possible to commute things like this ($Π$ and products behave nicely together).
The answer is roughly the same if you replace 'polymorphism' with 'naturality' for category theory, and use a notation that conflates natural transformations with individual arrows making them up. Equations might only hold up to the implicit details, and that means they cannot be used to substitute at the level of notation if the equations are derived only for specific meanings of that notation.

Nice! This parallels the explanations other community members have figured out here.
